# Track my lost laptop

Tags: laptop, security, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prepare your PC or laptop for theft](https://superuser.com/questions/17701/how-to-prepare-your-pc-or-laptop-for-theft)

Today I was searching for some software which can track my lost laptop. There, I found a software for Windows XP and Vista which provides the following features:

- Geo-location is determined by wi-fi signal
- Remotely delete files from the stolen laptop
- Remotely retrieve files from the stolen laptop
- Monitor and control everything the thief does
- Lock down the stolen laptop if desired

Can somebody please help me to know, how one can automatically enable remote connection to the laptop and retrieve or delete files, monitor the thief (i.e. set webcam on automatically) and lock the system?

Comment: Once it's been stolen, there's no real way of connecting to it, unless you've installed the tracking software **before the actual event**.

Comment: Is it already lost? If so then ignore my answer below, there is no way to remote connect to it.

Comment: For additional information, you can look here: http://superuser.com/questions/17701/how-to-prepare-your-pc-or-laptop-for-theft

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use a password to login to your laptop? If so, I don't see how phone-home software can run automatically.

Comment: @kbmonkey, a service can run at computer start, even before a user is logged in.

Comment: @snark good point. I just realized a login screen will only get one reaction: power off.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [logmein.com](https://secure.logmein.com/US/home.aspx)

Seems silly but, it will automatically connect when it has access to the internet, you can set it to send out no notification of connection, and it means if the thief leaves it on to download something you can activate gps, web cam etc

Answer (score 1):

> [LAlarm™](http://lalarm.com/en/Lalarm_Laptop_Alarm.htm) is free laptop alarm
>   security software. LAlarm sounds an
>   alarm when a laptop is in danger of
>   being stolen or losing data, and it
>   can recover and destroy data if the
>   laptop is stolen. LAlarm consists of
>   five alarms and other security
>   functions designed to protect laptops
>   and sensitive data.

FAQ are [here](http://lalarm.com/en/FAQ.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial packages.  I have read many good things about this one.  I believe Dell offers something like this as an option.

http://www.absolute.com/products/lojackforlaptops

I guess a great deal depends on what value you place on the hardware and data

Comment: It uses the BIOS firmware to persist after a drive format or reinstall, even for Linux, nice.